# Joining and resolving two paths while keeping them relative conditionally

Tags: powershell

I would like to have a function `Chain-Paths` to accomplish the following: given a base directory (`Base`) and a location, possibly relative to that given Base (`Chained`), output the result of joining both paths. If however `Chained` is already an absolute path, just return that. If both paths are relative, keep the result relative as well.

The above, reformulated in test cases (works if run from a user directory, e.g. *C:\Users\ojdo*):

```
$testCases = @(
    @{
        Base = "..\..\Windows\Fonts"
        Chained = "..\system32\notepad.exe"
        Expected = "..\..\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
    }
    @{
        Base = "C:\Windows\Fonts"
        Chained = "..\system32\notepad.exe"
        Expected = "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
    }
    @{

        Base = "AppData\Roaming"
        Chained = "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
        Expected = "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
    }
)

foreach ($case in $testCases) {
    $expectedResult = $case.Expected
    $actualResult = (Chain-Paths $case.Base $case.Chained)
    $testResult = if($actualResult -eq $expectedResult) {"PASS"} else {"FAIL"}

    Write-Host ("{0}: {1} == {2}" -f $testResult, $actualResult, $expectedResult)
}
```

This is the function I have come up with:

```
function Chain-Paths($Base, $Chained)
{
    if (Split-Path $Chained -IsAbsolute) {
        return $Chained
    } else {
        $joinedPath = Join-Path $Base $Chained
        if (Split-Path $Base -IsAbsolute) {
            return (Resolve-Path $joinedPath).Path
        } else {
            return Resolve-Path $joinedPath -Relative
        }
    }
}
```

My questions:

- Am I overcomplicating things?
- Is there a way to simplify things by using a .net function?
- Is the `(...).Path` really required?
- Any stylistic recommendations (apart from missing docstring)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [System.IO.Path.Combine Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> This method is intended to concatenate individual strings into a single string that represents a file path. However, if an argument other than the first contains a rooted path, any previous path components are ignored, and the returned string begins with that rooted path component.

```
$combined = [IO.Path]::Combine($Base, $Chained)
```

Also, it seems more natural to use `System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted()` method instead of `Split-Path` to see if the path is absolute.

```
$isRelative = ![IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($combined)
```

There is a way to pass parameter values by appending a colon after the parameter name in cmdlet. You can also pass values to the `switch` type parameter this way.

```
Verb-Noun -ParameterName:Value
```

`Resolve-Path` basically outputs a `PathInfo` object, but when the `-Relative` switch is set the output will be `string`.
Both types have a `ToString ()` method, so you can get a path string without using an `if` statement. (The `ToString()` method of the `PathInfo` object outputs the value of the `Path` property)

```
function Chain-Path($Base, $Chained) {
    $combined = [IO.Path]::Combine($Base, $Chained)
    $isRelative = ![IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($combined)
    (Resolve-Path $combined -Relative:$isRelative).ToString()
}
```